# Problem communicating with GSM module which is a Fona 3G from adafruit

Tags: communication, gsm, adafruit, wireless, uart

My issue is fairly simple to describe but I have no idea what the problem could be. So I got my FONA 3G and immediately after taking it out of the box, I connected the battery and I wired up my FTDI board (aka USB to serial converter), and then I plugged it into my USB port to try and establish communication. I just tried the most basic at command AT(using PuTTy). You're supposed to get an OK in response but the FONA doesn't appear to even notice that I'm trying to talk to it. I type AT and press enter and nothing happens at all.

The issue is most certainly not my FTDI board, I'm very experienced communicating with wifi modules and other GSM modules using PuTTy. So please don't be concerned with the setup. That's 100 percent definitely not the problem.

I was able to send AT commands after plugging the module into my laptop directly using the module's USB input, but there is still some issue with its UART. I haven't been able to send or receive any communications directly from RX and TX. It wont respond to any programs I load up onto my arduino. Its like the UART is asleep.

If you have experience with FONA 3G, please speak up and tell me what steps you took to get the UART to respond. What should the status indicator look like before its ready to receive commands? Any knowledge you have about the FONA3G module would be helpful.

As a side note, the FONA3G has a chip number. It is SIM5320a. I don't know if that helps. Most people know it as FONA 3G.

Comment: If your Fona3G is not even reacting to Putty AT commands, you set everything up  perfectly there is only one possibility left. Power supply not sufficient or DOA -in that case let it replace by the seller or go to a repair store if its a used one

Comment: It's been my experience that when a poster is 100% sure that the problem doesn't lie in one particular area, about 50% of the time we end up finding the problem in that area.  Mostly because the OP has probably looked at everything else, but isn't looking where they're sure the problem isn't.  Look even experts make dumb mistakes and miswire something sometimes.  I surely doesn't hurt you at all to show that part.  It's amazing what another set of eyes can catch sometimes.  Smart folks get the details out when they want help.  It's foolish to hide things in a case like this.

Comment: Okay I realize thats a common thing. But I have never had issues like this with other devices. I'm experienced in working with the UART. Some devices need to be reset before they'll respond to AT commands. I was wondering if someone who has used this module before knows what the trick is to get it to respond. That's all.

Answer (score 0):

All right. Thanks to those of you who posted comments. It turned out to be an issue with the baud rate! Its always the simple stuff. Adafruit said this thing has auto baud meaning you can use any baud rate but they are wrong. It requires 115200 to work properly. Also I'd like to point out that there was nothing wrong with my setup. Sometimes you should trust the person when they say their setup is 100 percent fine.